# BAST & FAST Algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, memory, memory-management, genetic-algorithm

Are there any algorithms named BAST & FAST related to the memory simulator? I know algorithms like Fast sigmoid etc but can't find any algorithms related to memory simulator. Can anyone with knowledge of this explain it to me or provide a link as every time, I try to search it the internet shows results of BEST algorithms or FAST algorithms.